# How to include xsl style sheet in xml file using java

Tags: java, xml, xslt

As part of selenium, we are generating result files in the form of xml.
now we are generating file like "ReportManager.xml"
in this file we want to add a xsl stylesheet link in the second line,

Here is the code of:Report Magaer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ReportManager><SmokeTest><Version DisplayName="ERP Build: ERP 9">
<Family DisplayName="Module">
<Product DisplayName="Branch Setup"/>
<Product DisplayName="Academics Module"/>
<Product DisplayName="Admission Process"/>
<Product DisplayName="Examination Settings"/>
<Product DisplayName="Examination Production"/>
<Product DisplayName="Delete Master Activity Remarks">
<Report ActualResult="Activity Deleted :etetettre is shown" Executed="Wed Jan 20 12:08:02 IST 2016" ExpectedResult="Activity Deleted :etetettre should be shown" Status="Pass" StepNumber="1"/>
<Report ActualResult="Activity Deleted :wfdreqfreqwreeeeeee is shown" Executed="Wed Jan 20 12:08:21 IST 2016" ExpectedResult="Activity Deleted :wfdreqfreqwreeeeeee should be shown" Status="Pass" StepNumber="1"/>
</Product>
</Family>
</Version>
</SmokeTest>
</ReportManager>
```

now i want to include the line

```
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='ReportManager.xsl'?>
```

in the second line dynamically, Please let me know how can we write this script in java.

Comment: Not sure what you mean: `System.out.println("<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>");` `System.out.println(`**<your missing line>**`);` 
`System.out.println("<ReportManager><SmokeTest><Version DisplayName=""ERP Build: ERP 9""...`is probably not what you want? Please explain so that we can understand

Answer (score 0):

don't know what do you actually mean by it but if u already have  an xsl and input xml then  you can transform them using the following java code, hope it helps

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class XMLTransformationEndingTag {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException, TransformerException {

        String XMLFile="<path for your xml file>";
        String XSLFile="<path for your xsl file>";

        TransformerFactory fac = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Source xslt= new StreamSource(new File(XSLFile));
        Transformer trans = fac.newTransformer(xslt);

        Source text=new StreamSource(new File(XMLFile));
        trans.transform(text, new StreamResult(new File("file.xml")));

    }

}
```